# How to send email through contact.html template in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Here is my contact.html code

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
                            
form class="form-area " id="myForm" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post" class="contact-form text-right">

<div class="row">

{% csrf_token %}    
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">

<input name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
                                    
<input name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="email">

<input name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter subject'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
<textarea class="common-textarea form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter Messege" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Messege'" required=""></textarea>   
</div>
```

and here is my views.py file

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    subject = request.POST['subject']
    message = request.POST['message']

    send an email 
    send_mail(
        subject,
        name,
        message,
        email,
        ['nishantkkr68@gmail.com'],
        fail_silently= False
    )
    return render(request,'contact.html',{'name': name})
else:
    return render(request,'contact.html',{})
```

Here is my settings.py file

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST = '1025'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

It seems my action button in contact.html is not doing any job
(NOTE: My localhost 1025 is working)

How can I solve this please help

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For sending mail you have to use django mail package. You can follow below code :

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from django.template.loader import get_template

def send_email_smtp(from_email, recipient_list, subject, body):
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, recipient_list)
    msg.attach_alternative(body, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    return True, None

name = request.POST['name']
recipient_email = request.POST['email']
subject = request.POST['subject']
message = request.POST['message']

html_template = get_template('email_template.html')
html_content = html_template.render(
    {
        'message': message,
    })
send_email_smtp(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recipient_email],
                subject, body=html_content)
```

Apart from this you have to create one template for email body called "email_template.html". I provide simple snippet for that ...

```
File name : email_template.html
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1> {{ message }} </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Add following variables in settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'nishantkkr68@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your email password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And also you have to give permission to your email for access less secure app. You can give that using this [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

For simple form template "contact.html" follow below code snippet :

```html
<form class="your css classes" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">

<input name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
                                    
<input name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="email">

<input name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter subject'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
<textarea class="common-textarea form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter Messege" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Messege'" required=""></textarea>   
</div>
<input type="submit" class="" value="submit" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
</form>
```

Or else you can follow this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-form-using-django-forms/) for how to manage form in django

Comment: Use also have to add this property setting.py :
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = Ture

Comment: Brother please email me on nishantkkr68@gmail.com so that I can send you the total contact.html file and after viewing that tell me what should I do to solve my problem.

Comment: @NishantSagar You can provide that file here only.

Comment: @NishantSagar please review updated answer and you can reach me on Linkedin  this is my profile [link](https://www.linkedin.com/in/parthghinaiya477/) .